# SQLite VBA libraries - do they require registered components?

Tags: sqlite, vba

Aeons ago I found a standalone DLL that could be dropped into a folder with an Excel or Word doc and used to access a local SQLite db without installing anything on the client machine. It was rather basic and not as robust as I'd liked. I wonder if any recent solutions can also be deployed by copying the DLL into the same folder as the workbook or worksheet to access a DB, or if some kind of ODBC needs to be set up.

Comment: If you just need an SQL database then Excel + ADO + Jet should work on pretty much any installation out of the box

Comment: I want SQLite. That was essential to my question.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem, you do not [wish to use ODBC drivers](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/)? You can read SQLite in Excel or Word handily enough with ODBC drivers and ADO.

Some notes:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

scn = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\docs\ex1;" _
& "LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;"

cn.ConnectionString = scn
cn.Open

cn.Execute "CREATE TABLE tbl2 (ID int, Stuff Text(50))"

cn.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl2 (ID, Stuff) VALUES (2, 'def')"
s = "SELECT * FROM tbl2"

rs.Open s, cn

Debug.Print rs.GetString
```

See: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite

Comment: Exactly. The users may not have admin rights and I don't want to deal with that grief.

Comment: @Remou aftef install sqliteodbc, i write this demo: http://pastebin.com/apFk0w8J But VBE pop-up error message: `Run-time error '424': Object required` How to connect to a sqlite file?

Comment: @Davuz You have `Dim a As New ADODB.Connection`, but you are using cn, you need to `Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection`